# spring ehcache integration with self-populating-cache-scope

Tags: ehcache

I have to integrate spring and ehcache, and trying to implement it with **blockingCache** pattern

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven/>
```

there is one option for **self-populating-cache-scope** for **shared (default) and method**. could you please explain what is the difference?

There is also the annotation **@Cacheable** with **selfPopulating** flag

As per what I read on some post

http://groups.google.com/group/ehcache-spring-annotations/browse_thread/thread/7dbc71ce34f6ee19/b057610167dfb815?lnk=raot

it says when **shared** is used **only one instance is created** and the same is used everytime the same cache name is used so if I use the **selfPopulating** flag as true for one method,

> all the threads trying to access **other methods** annotated with
>   **@Cacheable with selfPopulating flag set to true** will go on hold which
>   I dont want

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven/>
```

when **self-populating-cache-scope = method** on other hand creates **separate instances** for all methods annotated with @Cacheable with selfPopulating flag set to true so it doesn't create a problem.

But in this case when I try to remove a element using **@TriggerRemove** and giving the cache name used in @Cacheable will it search in each of those separate instances to find the value? Isnt this an overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Eric on the ehcache google group above

> In all cases there is one underlying Ehcache instance. What happens
>   when you set selfPopulating=true is a SelfPopulatingCache wrapper is
>   created.
>
> If cache-scope=shared then all annotations using that named cache will
>   use the same SelfPopulatingCache wrapper If cache-scope=method then
>   one wrapper is created per method
>
> Note in both cases the SelfPopulatingCache is a wrapper, there is
>   still only one actual cache backing the wrapper(s)
>
> As for blocking, If you read the docs for SelfPopulatingCache and
>   BlockingCache you'll notice that ehcache does a compromise between
>   cache level locking and per-key locking via key striping.
>   http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/BlockingCache.html